# Iterating through variables in a Python list in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

So I was making a simple web application where you enter some text and it shows up on the screen, sort of like a chat screen.

**My Python Code**

```
import sys
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

option_list = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sessions():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['message'] != '':
            option_list.append(request.form['message'])
        print(option_list, file = sys.stdout)
        return render_template("session.html", option_list = option_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <title>Text:</title>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;"></ul>
          {% for o in option_list %}
            <li>{{ o }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method = "post">
            <p><input type = "text" name = "message" autocomplete="off" /></p>
            <p><input type = "submit" name = sgnin value = "Send" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The logs and html both show that they are sending and receiving data. However, instead of printing the value of `o`, it just prints `o`. I'm pretty sure it's because of the HTML file. I'm sure this might be a rookie mistake, but any idea how to fix it?

Comment: try without space  <li>{{o}}</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just re-ran my code and it's working as it should, although I have no idea how it fixed itself.

Answer (score -1):

Change the return format use  return render_template("session.html", {'option_list': option_list)

```
import sys
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

option_list = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sessions():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.form['message'] != '':
         option_list.append(request.form['message'])
         print(option_list, file = sys.stdout)
     return render_template("session.html", {'option_list': option_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: This did not work. It gives me the error `TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`